# May I ask the same question on Stack Overflow if not answered on a different SE site?

Tags: discussion, cross-posting

On different stacks I've asked a few very specific questions that weren't answered. The [newest one](https://serverfault.com/questions/707866/list-all-kerberized-spns-in-linux) I asked on Server Fault. Of course I wouldn't ask it right away on Stack Overflow because I just posted it today but if I get another Tumbleweed badge, I would like to ask it here. There is the [kerberos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kerberos) tag, so it should be within the topic.

Is it okay to do that or should I just accept that no one knows an answer/wants to answer?

Comment: Keep in mind that it can also be the way you ask the question that nobody feels qualified to answer. Take the example you link to: you ask "Or is it even possible?"  - is anyone going to feel confident posting "no"? I don't think so, you'll only get answered by a chorus of crickets when you ask something like that.

Comment: @Gimby Well before I ask if it's possible, I ask for solutions^^ So if anyone would know a way they could answer. If someone with experience in Keberos under Linux says that he thinks it's not possible it would be enough for me, so I don't waste my time searching for something...

Comment: _If someone with experience in Keberos under Linux says that he thinks it's not possible_ Except that means guessing, and people generally don't like posting guesses as answers. You risk getting down votes from 1) someone who does know it is possible and 2) people who don't view guesses as real answers.

Comment: You shouldn't assume that your question will be on topic on Stack Overflow just because there is a tag broadly related to your question. Stack Overflow is for programming questions. The structure of your existing question makes it look very much like a question about administration tools. Unless you can show that programming is involved it's likely to be closed as off-topic on Stack Overflow, notwithstanding the Kerberos tag.